# Imprimir elemento de uma posição espefícica na lista

Tags: python, lista

Preciso fazer com que imprima o número de dias de agosto na lista, mas sem usar o for:

```
def how_many_days(month_number):

    """Returns the number of days in a month.
    WARNING: This function doesn't account for leap years!
    """

days_in_month = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]

#todo: return the correct value

# This test case should print 31, the number of days in the eighth month, August

print(how_many_days(8))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua função não está retornando nenhum resultado, você precisa chamar o **return** ao final da função passando o **numero do mês `-1`**, o `-1` é pq o array inicia a contagem no 0 e não no 1

```
def how_many_days(month_number):
  """Returns the number of days in a month.
  WARNING: This function doesn't account for leap years!
  """
  days_in_month = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
  return days_in_month[month_number - 1]

#todo: return the correct value
# This test case should print 31, the number of days in the eighth month, August
print(how_many_days(8))
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente José... obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Existem dois erros no seu código:

1. Falta o `return` na sua função `how_many_days`
2. Python precisa de indentação correta.

Para o seu código funcionar você precisa colocar o `return` na função e arrumar a indentação e como python começa no `0` é preciso retornar o número do mês - 1, veja:

```
def how_many_days(month_number):
    days_in_month = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
    return days_in_month[month_number-1];
# This test case should print 31, the number of days in the eighth month, August

print(how_many_days(8))
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/oaMb0d).

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente... muito obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

```
 def how_many_days(month_number):

   """Returns the number of days in a month.
      WARNING: This function doesn't account for leap years!
   """

   days_in_month = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]

   return days_in_month[month_number]          
print(how_many_days(7));
```

Assim está correto.

Comment: ótimo... funcionou muito bem.

Comment: Seu código não está retornando os dias de agosto, e sim o de setembro, sempre bom lembrar que o array inicia a contagem no 0